# Problems with DataLogging after Pebble SDK update to v4.0

Tags: pebble-sdk

After update to SDK v4.0 I've faced a problem when data sent to the phone via DataLogging are getting lost.
Getting obtained only few data batches from many and `sessionDidFinish` method of Data Logging delegate doesn’t fire. The same trouble with DataLogging occurs with apps of other developers and Pebble 1 watches.

*(iPhone 6 Plus, iOS 9.3.5; Pebble 1, Firmware v3.12.2)*

Answer (score 0):

Pebble team confirmed bug from their side.